# Docker containers and AppArmor profiles

Tags: linux, docker, apparmor

The [default AppArmor profile](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go) for Docker containers is an ["unattached profile"](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.apparmor.profiles.html#sec.apparmor.profiles.types.unattached). It doesn't name the program being confined.
According to the docs, an unattached profile need to be attached to a program. I guess this is what happens when I start a docker container with the `--security-opt apparmor=<profile-name>` flag. But how?

[In this example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/#nginx-example-profile), the profile is referenced for an nginx container. I suppose, the nginx process is being confined there, but they also "exec into" the container with bash and the confinements are reflected in that bash process too.

What happens behind the scenes when we use `--security-opt apparmor=...`?
What process does the profile get attached to? Any that gets executed in the container's context?

Comment: You can view the details in https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/35988abe20851979d53d4a8f790b4c1b8800a10d/libcontainer/apparmor/apparmor_linux.go